# IceCast mount point on Azure returns 404

Tags: azure, docker, icecast, puredata

I am deploying a docker container running an IceCast 2 server to an Azure App Service.
If I run the container locally I can connect a source (in my case a pure-data patch) to a live.mp3 mountpoint without a problem. However, when I try to connect from the same source to the IceCast server running on Azure I get a login failed message with an Azure specific 404 error code.

```
login failed!
server answered : HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Date: Thu, 02 Apr 2020 18:02:05 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 2778
```

I can reach the IceCast web GUI over a browser without a problem (http://...azurewebsites.net/).

Does anyone know what could be wrong? I am exposing port 8000 on my IceCast container which is bound to port 80 of the Azure app service.

Comment: welcome to [so] a programmer's forum. your questions seems to be about server-configuration, so i suggest you move it to [sf] instead.